# regex to match and replace two characters between string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string String a = "(3e4+2e2)sin(30)"; and i want to show it as a = "(3e4+2e2)*sin(30)";

I am not able to write a regular expression for this.

Comment: `a = a.replaceAll("\)sin", ")*sin");`

Comment: and what if i have a String a = "(3e4+2e2)cos(30)"; i want to a have regular expression for all the characters not just sin or cos please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `replaceAll`:

```
a = a.replaceAll("\) *(\\w+)", ")*$1");
```

Comment: can you explain it a bit please why we use \\w+ and what is $1 and *(\\w+)

Comment: `\\w+` to match any word after `)` and `$1` is the back reference of that word (captured group #1) in the replacement string.

Comment: *(\\w+) and why you put closure after some space ?

Comment: Round parentheses are used to capture the enclosed pattern in a captured group.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this

```
String func = "sin";// or any function you want like cos.
String a = "(3e4+2e2)sin(30)";
a = a.replaceAll("[)]" + func, ")*siz");
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: and what if i have a String a = "(3e4+2e2)cos(30)"; i want to a have regular expression for all the characters not just sin or cos please help

Comment: You need to store your function in a variable, then do the `replaceAll`. see the updates in my answer.

Comment: i want only ) will change with )* not any character after and only those ) which are before any character or digit

Answer (score 0):

I did not try but the following should work

```
String a = "(3e4+2e2)sin(30)";
a = a.replaceAll("[)](\\w+)", ")*$1");
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
a = a.replaceAll("\\)(\\s)*([^*+/-])", ") * $2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String input = "(3e4+2e2)sin(30)".replaceAll("(\\(.+?\\))(.+)", "$1*$2"); //(3e4+2e2)*sin(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the characters within the first parenthesis will always be in similar pattern, you can split this string into two at the position where you would like to insert the character and then form the final string by appending the first half of the string, new character and second half of the string.

```
        string a = "(3e4+2e2)sin(30)";

        string[] splitArray1 = Regex.Split(a, @"^\(\w+[+]\w+\)");
        string[] splitArray2 = Regex.Split(a, @"\w+\([0-9]+\)$");

        string updatedInput = splitArray2[0] + "*" + splitArray1[1];

        Console.WriteLine("Input = {0}   Output = {1}", a, updatedInput);
```